# VBA running sum

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say I have 2 columns (the following table includes the result)

```
Product ID    Price    Average
1             4        5
1             4        5
1             7        5
2             3        3
2             3        3
3             9        9
```

I want to be able to write a VBA code to loop through the rows of Product IDs and create the 3rd column which has average out the Prices.

I guess a For statement would work, but how do I define temp variables to store each ID?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `WorksheetFunction.AverageIf()` or just using `Evaluate("=Averageif(" & SomethingHere & ")")`, and you will not need to store each ID  in variable. Also, you can apply the formula to the whole range and remove formulas after.

Comment: Is there a special reason for putting a VBA loop in, when AVERAGEIF can do what you want in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

As Vasily and L.Dutch told, `AVERAGEIF()` function is all you need. If you want to loop it through all cells, you can use `Do While` loop like this:

```
Sub avg()
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Do While Range("A" & i).Value <> ""
    Range("C" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGEIF(C1,RC1,C2)"
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```